How can I change the position of a row in a DataTable of a DataSet with Relations set?
I tried this first.
Link : How to move a DataTable row to the first position of its DataTable

for Sample...

DataSet.Table[0]
key  | master
 1   |   A
 2   |   B
 3   |   C

DataSet.Table[1]
key  | detail
 1   |   10
 1   |   20
 1   |   30
 2   |   23
 3   |   45
 3   |   25

C# Code
 ds.Relations.Add("key", ds.Tables[0].Columns["key"], ds.Tables[1].Columns["key"]);

 DataRow moveRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[2];
 DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
 newRow.ItemArray = moveRow.ItemArray;
 ds.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(moveRow);          // ★ Error
 ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);

Result is...
DataSet.Table[0]
key  | master
 3   |   C
 1   |   A
 2   |   B

DataSet.Table[1]
key  | detail
 1   |   10
 1   |   20
 1   |   30
 2   |   23

As you can see, all the Rows in the detail where the key corresponds to 3 have been removed.

I Want this result.
DataSet.Table[0]
key  | master
 3   |   C
 1   |   A
 2   |   B

DataSet.Table[1]
key  | detail
 1   |   10
 1   |   20
 1   |   30
 2   |   23
 3   |   45
 3   |   25


I tried clearing and resetting ds.Relations, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. Is there a better way?

Thank you.

Tried your code in net8, did not get any error. Perhaps add the complete code to produce the error and also which version of .net you are running.

You have the ds and set variables. Are these two different DataSets? Or is it a typo?

You add another column called "SortOrder" or something, and for rows A,B,C you have SortOrder have values of 2,3,1 respectively. Then you sort your table by them and enumerate the sorted result and voila! The rows are in the order you wanted. If you don't want another column you can use something independent, like a dictionary, to map your table keys to a sorting value that makes sense. A BindingSource can filter, sort and host data relations

@Magnus I revised the question once more to make it clearer.
A [logical error] appears at the location marked with the 'Error' comment, rather than a [build error]. The error occurs because it deletes all data in the Detail where the key is 3.

Did you try ds.EnforceConstraints = false;

It should work:
var dataRelation = ds.Relations.Add("key", ds.Tables[0].Columns["key"], ds.Tables[1].Columns["key"]);

// Disable constraints and cancel cascading deletion.
ds.EnforceConstraints = false;
dataRelation.ChildKeyConstraint.DeleteRule = Rule.None;

DataRow moveRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[2];
DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
newRow.ItemArray = moveRow.ItemArray;
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(moveRow);
ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);

// Now return constraints and cascading deletion.
ds.EnforceConstraints = true;
dataRelation.ChildKeyConstraint.DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade;

